# properly infinite $C^*$-algebra $B(H)$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

There is a conclusion:If $H$ is an infinite dimensional Hibert space,then $B(H)$ is a properly infinite $C^*$-algebra.

According to the definition,we need to find mutually orthogonal projections $e,f\in B(H)$ such that $e\leq id_H,f\leq id_H$ and $e,f$ are equivalent to $id_H$.

I try to choose $e=id_H,f=UU^*$,where $U$ is an unilateral shift operator,but it doesn't satisfy the condition:$ef=fe=0$,I also attempted to define $e=e_1\otimes e_1,f=e_2\otimes e_2$,but $e$ is not equivalent to $id_H$.

My question: how to find projections $e,f$ fulfill the above conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{e_i:i\in I\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$.  Since $I$ is infinite, we can find two disjoint subsets $A,B\subset I$ and bijections $f_A:I\to A$, $f_B:I\to B$.  Then let $e$ be the projection onto $\overline{\operatorname{span}}\{e_i:i\in A\}$, and let $f$ be the projection onto $\overline{\operatorname{span}}\{e_i:i\in B\}$.  Then $e\perp f$.  To show that $e\sim_{\operatorname{MvN}} 1$, define $u\in B(H)$ by linear extension of $u(e_i)=e_{f_A(i)}$.  Then $u^*u=1$, and $uu^*=e$.  Showing that $f\sim_{\operatorname{MvN}} 1$ is similar.

Comment: why can we find the two bijections?It is obvious that we can find an injective map,but how to assure that the injective map is also surjective?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281940/splitting-infinite-sets-into-disjoint-sets-of-equal-cardinality), and its answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I have another question:$u(e_i)=e_{f_A(i)}$,does it mean that "$u(e_i)=e_{f_A(i)}$ when $i \in A$,$u(e_i)=0$ when $i\not \in A$?

Comment: No, it means that for all $i\in I$, $u(e_i)=e_{f_A(i)}$.  Then $u^*(e_i)=e_{f_A^{-1}(i)}$ if $i\in A$ and $u^*(e_i)=0$ when $i\notin A$.

Comment: But the domain of $f_A$ is $A$,if $i\not \in A$,what is the value of $f_A(i)$?

Comment: You're right, sorry. I meant to have $I$ as the domain of $f_A$. I'll edit the answer.