# Isometries with orthogonal ranges

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

> Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. Prove that there
> exists two isometries $S_1, S_2\in \mathcal{B}(H)$ such that
> $\text{im}(S_1) \perp \text{im}(S_2)$

**Proof attempt:** When $H$ is separable (it has a countable  orthonormal basis $\{e_i: i\in \mathbb{N}\}$) we can define $S_1e_i = e_{2i-1}$ and $S_2e_i=e_{2i}$ and get the required result by noting that every $x\in H$ can be written as
$$x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle x, e_i\rangle e_i$$
But when $H$ is not separable, the best I could come up with is to consider an orthonormal family $E = \{e_i: i\in \mathbb{N}\}$, let $M=\overline{\text{span}E}$ and write $H=M\oplus M^{\perp}$. Then I could define $S_1$ and $S_2$ as before on $M$ and as the identities on $M^\perp$. This way, $S_1$ and $S_2$ remain isometries, but now their ranges aren't orthogonal anymore.

Comment: Why not take an actual orthonormal basis, rather than just an orthonormal family?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey If $H$ is not separable then it doesn't have an orthonormal basis.

Comment: That is not true; any Hilbert space has an orthonormal basis.  (It will just be uncountable if $H$ is not separable.)

Comment: @EricWofsey You're right. I meant a countable one. In my reference book, there isn't anything mentioned about uncountable bases (I'm not sure how to define convergence for series with uncountably many terms and even if I could I still don't know if Parsevals' equality holds in that case, although I guess it will)

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis In the uncountable setting, infinite linear combinations are still countable in the sense that only (at most) countably many of the coefficients are non-zero. Parseval's equality indeed still holds.

Comment: @EricWofsey My set theory is not great but in the uncountable case ($\{e_i : i\in I\}$) then there exist two uncountable subsets $I_1, I_2$ that partition $I$ with each having the same cardinality as $I$ (?) so we have two bijections $f_1 : I \to I_1$ and $f_2: I \to I_2$. Then we can define $S_1 e_i = e_{f_1(i)}$ and $S_2 e_i = e_{f_2(i)}$. Is what am saying at least a little bit reasonable (though I guess it's wrong)?

Comment: @TheoBendit I see. But still, the even-odd trick when defining $S_1$ and $S_2$ won't work since different coefficients will be zero for different vectors, right? Also, is what I'm saying above at least on the right direction?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis "Even and odd" won't technically work, since they apply to countable sets like $\Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{N}$. But, I believe it is true more generally that, given an infinite set $B$, you can decompose $B$ into two sets of the same cardinality of $B$. Equivalently, $|\{0, 1\} \times B| = |B|$. I don't know my basic cardinal arithmetic well enough to prove this, but this seems to be the salient point here.

Comment: @TheoBendit So I guess it all comes down to proving that if $I$ has cardinality $\kappa$ there exist two disjoint subsets $I_1,I_2$, both with cardinality $\kappa$?

Comment: Well, I would say a partition into two such subsets, but yes. This is equivalent to finding a bijection between $\{0, 1\} \times B$ and $B$.

Comment: @TheoBendit I guess [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281940/splitting-infinite-sets-into-disjoint-sets-of-equal-cardinality) answers the problem then.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Yes, though this also leaves the burning question about how to construct this decomposition open. I didn't realise that it was equivalent to axiom of choice, which is interesting, so such a construction could not be explicit.